# Opening an image with its original file name on display using Python?

Tags: python

I have a chart function that saves the end figure as a file. After I run the function, I also want it to display the figure at the end. So, I use this:

```
from PIL import Image

filepath = 'image.png'
img = Image.open(filepath)
img.show()
```

It works just fine, but when the file opens, it opens with a random file name, not the actual file name.

[image: random file name]

This can get troublesome as I have a lot of different chart functions that work in a similar fashion, so having logical names is a plus.

Is there a way I can open an image file with Python and have it display it's original file name?

**EDIT**

I'm using Windows, btw.

**EDIT2**

Updated the example with code that shows the same behaviour.

Comment: Where does `file['path']` come from?  PIL won't just invent a random name.  You must be giving it that name.

Comment: If the file came via some uploads for eg in flask, a temp file will be generated with random name. Is that the case ?

Comment: Possibly you're opening an image from inside a .zip archive? In that case, it may have been extracted to a temporary location to allow viewing, and that might be its name. You should probably share the actual code, or come up with a fully functional example that shows the same behaviour

Comment: @TimRoberts "file" is a dict I use to store some file and function related values. e.g.:
file = {'name': name, 'path': path, 'func': func}

I generate the name based on the function name and a timestamp.

Comment: OK, file is a dict. What's in it?  Where does it come from?  What if you print file['dict'] so you can see what it is?

Comment: @Grismar Everything is done locally on my PC and not from upload/download or .zip archive. Thanks for the advice though, I'll try to replicate this with some actual code and post it.

Comment: @PaulCornelius I've updated the description without the dict to make the issue less confusing.

Comment: OK, but where does the filename come from?  You already have a variable named 'filepath', so you are obviously not using that.  What ARE you using?

Comment: @PaulCornelius I've already answered this above: "I generate the name based on the function name and a timestamp." But I don't think matters. If I simply take any image file, rename it to 'image.png' and place it in the same folder as my code, I can reproduce the same results.

Comment: Sorry, still not making sense to me.  You say you want the "actual file name" but you talk about generating a name.  In your original question you say that the "file opens with a random file name."  Why do you think that?  Where are you getting this random file name?  Are you displaying the variable "img.filename," which according to the PIL docs contains the name of the original file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `PIL` you could use this:-

```
import os
filepath = "path"
os.startfile(filepath)
```

Using this method will open the file using system editor.

Or with `PIL`,

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk  # Place this at the end (to avoid any conflicts/errors)

window = tk.Tk()
#window.geometry("500x500") # (optional)    
imagefile = {path_to_your_image_file}
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imagefile))
lbl = tk.Label(window, image = img).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The first example (with os) works perfectly! Thank you, sir.

Comment: @Brakedown good to see that you are happy.

Answer (score 2):

The function img.show() opens a Windows utility to display the image.  The image is first written to a temporary file before it is displayed.  Here is the section from the PIL docs.
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.show

> Image.show(title=None, command=None)[source] Displays this image. This
> method is mainly intended for debugging purposes.
>
> This method calls PIL.ImageShow.show() internally. You can use
> PIL.ImageShow.register() to override its default behaviour.
>
> The image is first saved to a temporary file. By default, it will be
> in PNG format.
>
> On Unix, the image is then opened using the display, eog or xv
> utility, depending on which one can be found.
>
> On macOS, the image is opened with the native Preview application.
>
> On Windows, the image is opened with the standard PNG display utility.
>
> Parameters title – Optional title to use for the image window, where
> possible.
> "

The issue is that PIL uses a quick-and-dirty method for showing your image, and it's not intended for serious application use.

Comment: This explains the issue perfectly. Thanks for this!